# object-oriented database design

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm new to the world of database design, so I have some very basic questions. I'd like to create a database of people each of whom can take zero or more tests. Each test will have a description, a score and a date associated with it. Coming from an object-oriented background this sounds trivial, however I'm having some trouble finding any mention of a similar scenario using mySQL (or any other database language/platform).

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

Create three tables: users, tests, submissions.

The 'users' table will hold information about each person.

The 'tests' table will hold information about each test.

The 'submissions' table will tie the other two tables together. When a user takes a test, you'll add the user's ID, the test's ID and a timestamp to the 'submissions' table. By doing so, you can query to see which users have taken which tests and at what times.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Score could also be kept in the submissions table

Comment: Yeah, more or less. Does this let me associate more than 1 test with a user? Let's say I wanted to get test score #2 for each user, and some users didn't have a score #2, would that be possible?

Comment: Yes. You would have multiple entries with the same user ID pointing to different test IDs. So, if test two's ID number was '235', you'd select the users from the table where test ID = '235'. Users without an entry for test two would not be returned.

Comment: @HH - Your 'submissions' table should look something like this: ID (unique), User ID, Test ID, score, timestamp. When a user submits a test, a new row in this table is entered with the user's ID, the test's ID and (optionally) a calculated score. As long as each test has a unique ID, obtaining results from the table should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is a [relational database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database).  That means the objects are represented as tables.  These tables are related by key values.

[Jerad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13825410/300257) gives the details of a relational representation of the Person and Test objects. The key values are the User ID and the Test ID.  In a relational database, instances of an object (rows in a table) are identified by a key value.

Jerad's Submission table defines the relationship between the User table and the Test table. A User can take more than one Test, and a Test can be taken by more than one User.